# Strange floating and padding in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have this simplified code:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Sign Up">
</div>
```

And the CSS for it:

```
input.submit{
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    float:right;
}
.container{
    background-color: #AAA;
    float:right;
    padding: 50px;
}
```

I expect the div to wrap around the input button, float to the right, and its size is equal to the button's size + the padding (50px). In other browsers it works perfectly, but there are 2 strange things happen in IE7:

1. The width of the div stretches to the whole webpage. If I remove float:right from CSS of input.submit, then the size of the div is correct.
2. The input button's width is also much larger than when the button is displayed in other browsers.

This is the doc type I use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Anyone know why these problems happen and how to solve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you need `float: right` on `input.submit`, so just remove it. If there is a reason you need it, you'll have to show me why - there might be a workaround.

To fix the second problem, add `overflow: visible` to `input.submit`.

After those two changes, it looks virtually the same in IE7 and IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/33vmm/

Comment: This is just the simplified code from a registration form. I want the button to float to the right, to align it with other elements. 
overflow:visible works fine. Thank you. Is this a bug of IE7?

Comment: Oh the form I want to make is almost the same with the sign up form in Facebook homepage, when you are not logged in. But the sign up button is floated to the right, aligning with the text boxes above.